# How to write data to xml in localhost?

Tags: php, xml, database, localhost

I am working to write data xml in localhost. But it doesnt write the datas. The PHP and XML file are in the same directory. When .php was executed, there was no response. How can I fix this problem?

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Infos>
<Info name="someone" mail="something@gmail.com" />
</Infos>
```

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
$testName = "Stephen"
$testMail = "example@gmail.com"

addInfoToXml(__DIR__ . "/test.xml","Infos","Info",$testName,$testMail);

function addInfoToXml($path,$parent,$child,$name,$mail)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
    $doc->load($path);

    $root = $doc->getElementsByTagName($parent)->item(0);

    $info = $doc->createElement($child);
    $info->setAttribute("adsoyad",$name);
    $info->setAttribute("mail",$mail);
    $info = $root->appendChild($info);

    $doc->save($path);
}

?>
```

Comment: try treating the $path as a real path and not a url... Or if the source is remote and the xml you are creating is local, supply a local and remote path (url or real path)... writing to a url usually requires more than just a write action, since your web service is a bit picky about what you request it to do.. I edited your question...

Answer (score 0):

Asides from missing the semi-colons from the declared variables as @Raphioly-San mentioned you ought to use the actual path rather than the url. Some error checking also might be a good idea.

```
$testName = "Stephen";
$testMail = "example@gmail.com";

addInfoToXml( __DIR__."\test.xml", "Infos", "Info", $testName, $testMail);

function addInfoToXml( $path, $parent, $child, $name, $mail ){
    $path=file_exists( realpath( $path ) ) ? realpath( $path ) : false;
    clearstatcache();

    if( $path ){
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
        $doc->load( $path );

        $root = $doc->getElementsByTagName( $parent )->item(0);
        if( $root ){
            $info = $doc->createElement( $child );
            $info->setAttribute("adsoyad",$name);
            $info->setAttribute("mail",$mail);
            $info = $root->appendChild($info);
            $doc->save($path);
        }
    } else {
        echo "error: incorrect path to xml file";   
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worked succesfully with a local path such as C:\users\....\test.xml. But still doesnt work with localhost. What is the main problem?

Comment: I have tested the chmod value of the xml file. The value is 444. It seems the file is only readable. Does it solve the problem to set chmod value as 777 and if it does how can I set the value?

Comment: You can read a file from a url but not write back to a url like this! Better is to use the actual path as shown

Comment: Never use backslashes when working with paths, but forward slashes (or use the seperator definition). They're for Windows only and they're interpreted as forward slashes within php and then translated back to nackslashes when hitting the OS layer.